# Avoid checkbox on top of clickable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a clickable div with a checkbox inside it.

```
<div class="card" onclick="location.href = 'www.google.com'">
 <input type="checkbox" class="selectable-item" />
</div
```

How do I avoid onclick on the checkbox. Maybe with javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/m64tqfdj/

Answer (score 0):

Here you're dealing with event bubling, which means that the event will propagate to the containing DOM elements of what you click.

The solution is to use `.stopPropagation` like this

```
<script>
 function clickHereOnly(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
 }
</script>

<div class="card" onclick="location.href = 'www.google.com'">
  <div >
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="clickHereOnly(event)" class="selectable-item" id="media_1"/>
    <label for="media_1"></label>
  </div>
  <h3>John</h3>
</div>
```